# Initializing `constexpr` Array with Pattern

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I would like to initialize a `constexpr` array with a pattern that is generated using variadic template parameters. For simplicity, consider the problem of initializing a `constexpr unsigned` static array with the sizes of a list of types, say, `unsigned, short, char, int, long`. How can I do this so that *all of the computation is done during compile time?* I need the solution to play nice with the C++ type system, so I cannot use macros.

The best I could come up with is shown below, <strike>but compilation using `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Ofast -S` (using g++ 4.7) and inspection of the assembly clearly reveals that the values are pushed onto the stack during runtime. Any ideas?</strike> **and works fine**.

Using an array initializer as follows would work if I could somehow tell the expansion *n +1* about expansion *n*.

`static constexpr unsigned foo[] = { compute_element<Args>::value... };`

**Edit:** Wait, never mind, I had a brainfart. The line above works fine...

**Here is the <strike>code</strike> answer**:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class... Args>
struct foo
{
    static constexpr unsigned bar[] = { sizeof(Args)... };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo<unsigned, short, char, int, long>::bar[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: It's encouraged that if you find an answer to your questions to post it as such. :)

Comment: Ok, I wrote the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer. Keep in mind that due to limitations in C++, I think that this can only be done in-compile time to create arrays that are of the same size of the variadic template parameter pack.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class... Args>
struct foo
{
    static constexpr unsigned bar[] = { sizeof(Args)... };
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo<unsigned, short, char, int, long>::bar[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```