# How to initialise a floating point array at compile time?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++14, constexpr

I have found two good approaches to initialise integral arrays at compile times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12108694) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981617).

Unfortunately, neither can be converted to initialise a float array straightforward; I find that I am not fit enough in template metaprogramming to solve this through trial-and-error.

First let me declare a use-case:

```
constexpr unsigned int SineLength  = 360u;
constexpr unsigned int ArrayLength = SineLength+(SineLength/4u);
constexpr double PI = 3.1415926535;

float array[ArrayLength];

void fillArray(unsigned int length)
{
  for(unsigned int i = 0u; i < length; ++i)
    array[i] = sin(double(i)*PI/180.*360./double(SineLength));
}
```

As you can see, as far as the availability of information goes, this array *could* be declared `constexpr`.

However, for the first approach linked, the generator function `f` would have to look like this:

```
constexpr float f(unsigned int i)
{
  return sin(double(i)*PI/180.*360./double(SineLength));
}
```

And that means that a template argument of type `float` is needed. Which is not allowed.

Now, the first idea that springs to mind would be to store the float in an int variable - nothing happens to the array indices after their calculation, so pretending that they were of another type than they are (as long as byte-length is equal) is perfectly fine.

But see:

```
constexpr int f(unsigned int i)
{
  float output = sin(double(i)*PI/180.*360./double(SineLength));
  return *(int*)&output;
}
```

is not a valid `constexpr`, as it contains more than the return statement.

```
constexpr int f(unsigned int i)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<int>(sin(double(i)*PI/180.*360./double(SineLength)));
}
```

does not work either; even though one might think that `reinterpret_cast` does exactly what is needed here (namely nothing), it apparently only works on pointers.

Following the second approach, the generator function would look slightly different:

```
template<size_t index> struct f
{
  enum : float{ value = sin(double(index)*PI/180.*360./double(SineLength)) };
};
```

With what is essentially the same problem: That enum cannot be of type `float` and the type cannot be masked as `int`.

---

Now, even though I have only approached the problem on the path of "pretend the `float` is an `int`", I do not actually like that path (aside from it not working). I would much prefer a way that actually handled the `float` as `float` (and would just as well handle a `double` as `double`), but I see no way to get around the type restriction imposed.

Sadly, there are many questions about this issue, which always refer to integral types, swamping the search for this specialised issue. Similarly, questions about masking one type as the other typically do not consider the restrictions of a `constexpr` or template parameter environment.
See [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13313980)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11509284)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20436611) and [[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8365143/3434465)[[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4149992/3434465) etc.

Comment: You won't have much luck creating a `constexpr` function based on `std::sin()` as this function isn't a `constexpr` function. Maybe it should be but as of now it isn't.

Comment: @DietmarKühl It's an intrinsic in some compilers. Also, implementing the series expansion isn't that hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taylor series expansion as constexpr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216359/taylor-series-expansion-as-constexpr)

Comment: Why not use Excel to do the maths and write a macro to spit out the source code for the array?

Comment: @Columbo: how does an implementation detail of some compilers help you writing portable code?

Comment: @DietmarKühl Who said the code is supposed to be portable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming your actual goal is to have a concise way to initialize an array of floating point numbers and it isn't necessarily spelled `float array[N]` or `double array[N]` but rather `std::array<float, N> array` or `std::array<double, N> array` this can be done.

The significance of the type of array is that `std::array<T, N>` can be copied - unlike `T[N]`. If it can be copied, you can obtain the content of the array from a function call, e.g.:

```
constexpr std::array<float, ArrayLength> array = fillArray<N>();
```

How does that help us? Well, when we can call a function taking an integer as an argument, we can use `std::make_index_sequence<N>` to give use a compile-time sequence of `std::size_t` from `0` to `N-1`. If we have that, we can initialize an array easily with a formula based on the index like this:

```
constexpr double const_sin(double x) { return x * 3.1; } // dummy...
template <std::size_t... I>
constexpr std::array<float, sizeof...(I)> fillArray(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return std::array<float, sizeof...(I)>{
            const_sin(double(I)*M_PI/180.*360./double(SineLength))...
        };
}

template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<float, N> fillArray() {
    return fillArray(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Assuming the function used to initialize the array elements is actually a `constexpr` expression, this approach can generate a `constexpr`. The function `const_sin()` which is there just for demonstration purpose does that but it, obviously, doesn't compute a reasonable approximation of `sin(x)`.

The comments indicate that the answer so far doesn't quite explain what's going on. So, let's break it down into digestible parts:

1. The goal is to produce a `constexpr` array filled with suitable sequence of values. However, the size of the array should be easily changeable by adjusting just the array size `N`. That is, conceptually, the objective is to create

   ```
   constexpr float array[N] = { f(0), f(1), ..., f(N-1) };
   ```

   Where `f()` is a suitable function producing a `constexpr`. For example, `f()` could be defined as

   ```
   constexpr float f(int i) {
       return const_sin(double(i) * M_PI / 180.0 * 360.0 / double(Length);
   }
   ```

   However, typing in the calls to `f(0)`, `f(1)`, etc. would need to change with every change of `N`. So, essentially the same as the above declaration should be done but without extra typing.
2. The first step towards the solution is to replace `float[N]` by `std:array<float, N>`: built-in arrays cannot be copied while `std::array<float, N>` can be copied. That is, the initialization could be delegated to to a function parameterized by `N`. That is, we'd use

   ```
   template <std::size_t N>
   constexpr std::array<float, N> fillArray() {
       // some magic explained below goes here
   }
   constexpr std::array<float, N> array = fillArray<N>();
   ```
3. Within the function we can't simply loop over the array because the non-`const` subscript operator isn't a `constexpr`. Instead, the array needs to be initialized upon creation. If we *had* a parameter pack `std::size_t... I` which represented the sequence `0, 1, .., N-1` we *could* just do

   ```
   std::array<float, N>{ f(I)... };
   ```

   as the expansion would effectively become equivalent to typing

   ```
   std::array<float, N>{ f(0), f(1), .., f(N-1) };
   ```

   So the question becomes: how to *get* such a parameter pack? I don't think it can be obtained directly in the function but it *can* be obtained by calling another function with a suitable parameter.
4. The using alias `std::make_index_sequence<N>` is an alias for the type `std::index_sequence<0, 1, .., N-1>`. The details of the implementation are a bit arcane but `std::make_index_sequence<N>`, `std::index_sequence<...>`, and friends are part of C++14 (they were proposed by [N3493](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3493.html) based on, e.g., on [this answer from me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059084/1120273)). That is, all we need to do is call an auxiliary function with a parameter of type `std::index_sequence<...>` and get the parameter pack from there:

   ```
   template <std::size_t...I>
   constexpr std::array<float, sizeof...(I)>
   fillArray(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
       return std::array<float, sizeof...(I)>{ f(I)... };
   }
   template <std::size_t N>
   constexpr std::array<float, N> fillArray() {
       return fillArray(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
   }
   ```

   The [unnamed] parameter to this function is only used to have the parameter pack `std::size_t... I` be deduced.

Comment: You can try your code on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) or Wandbox. Also, is this really answering the askers question? You can't guarantee static initialization of the above unless sin is intrinsic and the compiler decides to do it.

Comment: @Columbo: sometimes there are constraints on what can be done when you are at a work-place.

Comment: @Columbo: static initialization is _not_ constant initialization. It happens at run-time after constant initialization. The original question may have meant constant initialization. Also, since `sin()` is not guaranteed to be `constexpr` constant initialization cannot be guaranteed using this function anyway. If all involved operations are `constexpr` this also works for constant initialization.

Comment: I edited the code with something which compiles. Feel free to rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: @TartanLlama: thanks - that's essentialy just fixing silly typos/thinkos I couldn't catch...

Comment: It seems like both [Clang](http://goo.gl/mXJJcj) and [GCC](http://goo.gl/UYYa2e) are able to do this at compile time.

Comment: Actually, yo need to mark funtions constexpr and replace `sin` with custom compile-time sine implementation, and it will be `constexpr`

Comment: @DietmarKühl Although I really did mean to say constant initialization, static initialization is performed at compile time, no? It's constant initialization + zero initialization. Since zero initialization basically means zero-filling the data segment, that's done at compile time?

Comment: BTW, in C++14, in the `consexpr` case, a simple loop works also (instead of `index_sequence`).

Comment: @Columbo: yes, you are right. Static initialization is zero and constant initialization. However, the approach still works when all operations are made `constexpr`. On the implementation I have access to, `sin()` is not a `constexpr`. If there is a `constexpr` replacement it should work.

Comment: @Jarod42: using a loop won't work when using an `std::array<...>`, though, as its non-`const` subscript operator is not a `constexpr`. An array cannot be initialized directly to become a `constexpr`, i.e., a return type, e.g., `std::array<float, N>` is needed. I don't see how a loop can be used to initialize that type. It may be possible to use a different type. ... or use the `std::index_sequence` approach.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Indeed, my bad, I think they fix all subscript operators, but only the const one has been fixed.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation for `std::index_sequence` online (checked CPPReference, cplusplus.com and Google search; only hits are StackOverflow questions using it). Did you mean `std::integer_sequence`? In `constexpr std::array<float, ArrayLength> array = fillArray<N>();` if `ArrayLength` and `N` are different values, what is `N` (assuming that `ArrayLength` is defined as in the OP)? You do not actually seem to do anything with your `std::index_sequence` - then why use that instead of just counting down an integral recursion depth index?

Comment: Never mind the first question - I found `std::index_sequence` on the page for `std::integer_sequence` on cppreference.com.

Comment: "the array will actually initialized at run-time" - If that were the case, the declaration `constexpr <type> array` should **not** compile. As tested on GCC 4.9.2, using your example code as it is now (under assumption that `ArrayLength == N` in the assignment) does compile and does yield the appropriate array. The solution is also concise enough to be used. I still need to understand _how_ it works, though.

Comment: @Zsar: yes, the version using `const_sin()` can produce a `constexpr` array. When using `std::sin(x)` instead, there is no guarantee whether `std::sin(x)` is a `constexpr` function. Mismatching the array length of the `fillArray()` function and the array assigned to probably won't do you much good and they'd better be consistent. Otherwise I have added a bit more explanation to the answer.

Comment: This looks much better. Almost got it now. Final question (I promise): In order to incorporate my original `constexpr float f`, I added a leading `template<size_t> class functor` template parameter to both fillArray functions. In `fillArray()` I now have to specify that first template parameter for `fillArray(std::index_sequence)` explicitely in order to get the code to compile. For tidyness I would like to also specify the second one, but could not figure out how it should look like. My wrong assumption had been an exact duplicate of the function parameter, but what would be correct?

Comment: @Zsar: I'm not sure what you are doing and why it doesn't work. It should be straight forward to add parameters. To make the usage kind of nice, I'd try to package the initialization into a class taking a function object (probably one requiring `constexpr` constructors and operations) as constructor parameter and deducing the size of the target array by defining the initialization as a conversion operator to `std::array<T, N>`. However, I haven't experimented with getting something like this to fly.

Comment: I put a comment into the code I produced, outlining the problem:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c95f9fc688389b07

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example that generates a table of sin values, and that you can easily adapt to logarithm tables by passing a different function object

```
#include <array>    // array
#include <cmath>    // sin
#include <cstddef>  // size_t
#include <utility>  // index_sequence, make_index_sequence
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {

template<class Function, std::size_t... Indices>
constexpr auto make_array_helper(Function f, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
        -> std::array<decltype(f(std::size_t{})), sizeof...(Indices)>
{
        return {{ f(Indices)... }};
}

}       // namespace detail

template<std::size_t N, class Function>
constexpr auto make_array(Function f)
{
        return detail::make_array_helper(f, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

static auto const pi = std::acos(-1);
static auto const make_sin = [](int x) { return std::sin(pi * x / 180.0); };
static auto const sin_table = make_array<360>(make_sin);

int main() 
{
    for (auto elem : sin_table)
        std::cout << elem << "\n";
}
```

[**Live Example.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e689249173a590e3)

Note that you need to use `-stdlib=libc++` because `libstdc++` has a pretty inefficient implementation of `index_sequence`.

Also note that you need a `constexpr` function object (both `pi` and `std::sin` are not `constexpr`) to initialize the array truly at compile-time rather than at program initialization.

Comment: How does the efficiency of implementation show for an expression that is (supposed to be) eliminated at compile time and therefore will never be evaluated in a running program? The sole part making it into the compiled program would be the array itself, would it not be?

Comment: @Zsar yes, that would be the idea.

Comment: Well, alright but then... why the advice to switch libraries, if all it would affect were compile time?

Comment: To clarify, in the sixth comment to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17347935/3434465) someone else also mentions "efficiency" in the context of a `constexpr` expression. In their case (as they write about constexpr _functions_) I interpret this as meaning "_if_ the function had to be calculated at runtime, then _that_ would be inefficient". Here however, as the root of the callgraph is the assignment of a constexpr _variable_, **all** computation has to happen at compile time. What would the term "efficiency" mean in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems to overcome if you want to initialise a floating point array at compile time:

1. `std::array` is a little broken in that the `operator[]` is not constexpr in the case of a mutable constexpr std::array (I believe this will be fixed in the next release of the standard).
2. the functions in std::math are not marked constexpr!

I had a similar problem domain recently. I wanted to create an accurate but fast version of `sin(x)`.

I decided to see if it could be done with a `constexpr` cache with interpolation to get speed without loss of accuracy.

An advantage of making the cache constexpr is that the calculation of `sin(x)` for a value known at compile-time is that the `sin` is pre-computed and simply exists in the code as an immediate register load! In the worst case of a runtime argument, it's merely a constant array lookup followed by w weighted average.

This code will need to be compiled with `-fconstexpr-steps=2000000` on clang, or the equivalent in windows.

enjoy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace cpputil {

    // a fully constexpr version of array that allows incomplete
    // construction
    template<size_t N, class T>
    struct array
    {
        // public constructor defers to internal one for
        // conditional handling of missing arguments
        constexpr array(std::initializer_list<T> list)
        : array(list, std::make_index_sequence<N>())
        {

        }

        constexpr T& operator[](size_t i) noexcept {
            assert(i < N);
            return _data[i];
        }

        constexpr const T& operator[](size_t i) const noexcept {
            assert(i < N);
            return _data[i];
        }

        constexpr T& at(size_t i) noexcept {
            assert(i < N);
            return _data[i];
        }

        constexpr const T& at(size_t i) const noexcept {
            assert(i < N);
            return _data[i];
        }

        constexpr T* begin() {
            return std::addressof(_data[0]);
        }

        constexpr const T* begin() const {
            return std::addressof(_data[0]);
        }

        constexpr T* end() {
            // todo: maybe use std::addressof and disable compiler warnings
            // about array bounds that result
            return &_data[N];
        }

        constexpr const T* end() const {
            return &_data[N];
        }

        constexpr size_t size() const {
            return N;
        }

    private:

        T _data[N];

    private:

        // construct each element from the initialiser list if present
        // if not, default-construct
        template<size_t...Is>
        constexpr array(std::initializer_list<T> list, std::integer_sequence<size_t, Is...>)
        : _data {
            (
             Is >= list.size()
             ?
             T()
             :
             std::move(*(std::next(list.begin(), Is)))
             )...
        }
        {

        }
    };

    // convenience printer
    template<size_t N, class T>
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const array<N, T>& a)
    {
        os << "[";
        auto sep = " ";
        for (const auto& i : a) {
            os << sep << i;
            sep = ", ";
        }
        return os << " ]";
    }

}


namespace trig
{
    constexpr double pi() {
        return M_PI;
    }

    template<class T>
    auto constexpr to_radians(T degs) {
        return degs / 180.0 * pi();
    }

    // compile-time computation of a factorial
    constexpr double factorial(size_t x) {
        double result = 1.0;
        for (int i = 2 ; i <= x ; ++i)
            result *= double(i);
        return result;
    }

    // compile-time replacement for std::pow
    constexpr double power(double x, size_t n)
    {
        double result = 1;
        while (n--) {
            result *= x;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // compute a term in a taylor expansion at compile time
    constexpr double taylor_term(double x, size_t i)
    {
        int powers = 1 + (2 * i);
        double top = power(x, powers);
        double bottom = factorial(powers);
        auto term = top / bottom;
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            term = -term;
        return term;
    }

    // compute the sin(x) using `terms` terms in the taylor expansion        
    constexpr double taylor_expansion(double x, size_t terms)
    {
        auto result = x;
        for (int term = 1 ; term < terms ; ++term)
        {
            result += taylor_term(x, term);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // compute our interpolatable table as a constexpr
    template<size_t N = 1024>
    struct sin_table : cpputil::array<N, double>
    {
        static constexpr size_t cache_size = N;
        static constexpr double step_size = (pi() / 2) / cache_size;
        static constexpr double _360 = pi() * 2;
        static constexpr double _270 = pi() * 1.5;
        static constexpr double _180 = pi();
        static constexpr double _90 = pi() / 2;

        constexpr sin_table()
        : cpputil::array<N, double>({})
        {
            for(int slot = 0 ; slot < cache_size ; ++slot)
            {
                double val = trig::taylor_expansion(step_size * slot, 20);
                (*this)[slot] = val;
            }
        }

        double checked_interp_fw(double rads) const {
            size_t slot0 = size_t(rads / step_size);
            auto v0 = (slot0 >= this->size()) ? 1.0 : (*this)[slot0];

            size_t slot1 = slot0 + 1;
            auto v1 = (slot1 >= this->size()) ? 1.0 : (*this)[slot1];

            auto ratio = (rads - (slot0 * step_size)) / step_size;

            return (v1 * ratio) + (v0 * (1.0-ratio));
        }

        double interpolate(double rads) const
        {
            rads = std::fmod(rads, _360);
            if (rads < 0)
                rads = std::fmod(_360 - rads, _360);

            if (rads < _90) {
                return checked_interp_fw(rads);
            }
            else if (rads < _180) {
                return checked_interp_fw(_90 - (rads - _90));
            }
            else if (rads < _270) {
                return -checked_interp_fw(rads - _180);
            }
            else {
                return -checked_interp_fw(_90 - (rads - _270));
            }
        }


    };

    double sine(double x)
    {
        if (x < 0) {
            return -sine(-x);
        }
        else {
            constexpr sin_table<> table;
            return table.interpolate(x);
        }
    }

}


void check(float degs) {
    using namespace std;

    cout << "checking : " << degs << endl;
    auto mysin = trig::sine(trig::to_radians(degs));
    auto stdsin = std::sin(trig::to_radians(degs));
    auto error = stdsin - mysin;
    cout << "mine=" << mysin << ", std=" << stdsin << ", error=" << error << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

auto main() -> int
{

    check(0.5);
    check(30);
    check(45.4);
    check(90);
    check(151);
    check(180);
    check(195);
    check(89.5);
    check(91);
    check(270);
    check(305);
    check(360);
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
checking : 0.5
mine=0.00872653, std=0.00872654, error=2.15177e-09

checking : 30
mine=0.5, std=0.5, error=1.30766e-07

checking : 45.4
mine=0.712026, std=0.712026, error=2.07233e-07

checking : 90
mine=1, std=1, error=0

checking : 151
mine=0.48481, std=0.48481, error=2.42041e-08

checking : 180
mine=-0, std=1.22465e-16, error=1.22465e-16

checking : 195
mine=-0.258819, std=-0.258819, error=-6.76265e-08

checking : 89.5
mine=0.999962, std=0.999962, error=2.5215e-07

checking : 91
mine=0.999847, std=0.999848, error=2.76519e-07

checking : 270
mine=-1, std=-1, error=0

checking : 305
mine=-0.819152, std=-0.819152, error=-1.66545e-07

checking : 360
mine=0, std=-2.44929e-16, error=-2.44929e-16
```

Answer (score -2):

I am just keeping this answer for documentation. As the comments say, I was mislead by gcc being permissive. It fails, when `f(42)` is used e.g. as a template parameter like this:

```
std::array<int, f(42)> asdf;
```

**sorry, this was not a solution**

Separate the calculation of your float and the conversion to an int in two different constexpr functions:

```
constexpr int floatAsInt(float float_val) {
  return *(int*)&float_val;
}

constexpr int f(unsigned int i) {
  return floatAsInt(sin(double(i)*PI/180.*360./double(SineLength)));
}
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`s, as necessitated by your code, aren't permitted in constant expressions.

Comment: I just tried to compile that code with gcc. So either gcc is more permissive than the standard, or my solution is OK.

Comment: The former. GCC isn't compliant. (Did you try to execute the function? Right now, your code is ill-formed with no diagnostic required)

Comment: GCC [rejects](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a851ece783cf1c5) this if you use it in a context necessitating a constant expression.